# Mail merge (Parsec string formatting) example

Tags: parsing, haskell, formatting, parsec

My intent is to perform "mail merge" where I can write strings like `"hi <<name>>"` and format them according to a `HashMap`.

Specifically, the string contains keys formatted as `<<key>>`, and the map contains the corresponding values.

I have a **main concern** that I'd like help with. I think it would be best to perform the parsing in multiple stages:

- first find the `Key`s
- second find the remaining `Chunk`s
- and for more complicated parsing tasks, perhaps *more* stages

I couldn't figure that out and instead use the more expensive lookahead function `notFollowedBy` and one pass. That obviously wouldn't work well if I had a slightly more complicated need.

```
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity)
import Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

-- Parsing ----------

data Merge a = Chunk a | Key a deriving (Show)

key :: Parser (Merge String)
key = Key <$> between (string "<<") (string ">>") (many1 letter)

chunk :: Parser (Merge String)
chunk = Chunk <$> many1 (notFollowedBy key >> anyChar)

prose :: ParsecT String () Identity [Merge String]
prose = many1 $ key <|> chunk

-- Formatting ----------

format :: HM.HashMap String String -> [Merge String] -> String
format _ []             = ""
format hmap (Chunk x : xs) = x ++ format hmap xs
format hmap (Key k : xs) = 
  case HM.lookup k hmap of
    -- I could obviate the `error` by working within a failure monad
    Nothing -> error $ "missing key: " ++ k
    Just v -> v ++ format hmap xs

-- Testing ----------

testString = "Hi <<name>>! Do you like <<thing>>?"
testMap = HM.fromList [("name", "Adam"), ("thing", "Apples")]
main = print $ format testMap <$> parse prose "" testString
```

Comment: Do you allow nested `<<`? If they are not allowed, your language is regular.

Comment: @Zeta Like `<<<<>>`? No, there should just be alpha characters inside a `Key`.  Or if you meant `Key`s within `Key`s, still no, just `<<alpha>>`.

Comment: I'm really looking for some guidance on parsing in multiple passes, I couldn't quite figure out a convenient way to do that. Eg, how do I do a parse into tokens, and then parse my tokens (not strings).

Comment: You want to split your current implementation into lexing+parsing, instead of using a parser combinator as you do at the moment?

Comment: Isn't a parser for this way overkill? Sounds like [`breakOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html#v:breakOn) would do the job perfectly well.

Comment: so given that the language is regular... why do we go to the lengths of even discussing a full-fledged parser instead of a `unwords $ map ((flip HM.lookup) hmap) $ words text`?

Comment: @Vogel612 that would fail on `"<<name>>!"`.

Comment: It's not really hard to transform the concept to a character-level parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `notFollowedBy`, you can use `noneOf` in `chunk`:

```
chunk :: Parser (Merge String)
chunk = Chunk <$> many1 (noneOf "<") <|> try (sequence [char '<', noneOf "<"])
```

That prevents a lookahead but it is no longer that nice to look at.

---

`format` can be rewritten without explicit recursion if we use `concatMap`:

```
format :: HM.HashMap String String -> [Merge String] -> String
format hmap xs = concatMap go xs
  where
    go (Chunk c) = c
    go (Key   k) = maybe (error $ "missing key: " ++ k) id (HM.lookup k hmap)
```

However, this would make our function partial, which we try to prevent. So let's use `Either` instead:

```
format :: HM.HashMap String String -> [Merge String] -> Either String String
format hmap xs = concat <$> mapM go xs
  where
    go (Chunk c) = Right c
    go (Key   k) = maybe (Left $ "missing key: " ++ k) Right (HM.lookup k hmap)
```